# Is this eval() hackable?

Tags: python, escaping, eval, code-injection

I would like to make a function decorator which, before executing actual function, will do some actions with its variables. And these actions I would like to provide as `eval()` strings. Variables are the arguments of the function. Let me show you:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import getcallargs


def safeornot(*keys):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # get dict of arguments passed to the function
            func_args = getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
            # now these are made locally visible as normal variables inside the eval function
            _keys = []
            for key in keys:
                _key = eval(key, globals(), func_args)
                _keys.append(_key)
            print(_keys)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@safeornot('you + " " + __name__', 'you + " " + me')
def you_and_me(you, me):
    print("you and me")

you_and_me("1", "2")
```

will, obviously, print:

```
['1 __main__', '1 2']
you and me
```

which I'm aiming at.

But this function will be used in an unsafe environment: it's going to be a rate-limiting decorator for functions inside web app, so the `you` and `me` variables are as unsafe as they come.

Can this `eval()` be hacked into, for example, formatting the server? I kinda don't see it being hacked, as the `locals()` are not `eval`'ed themselves and are treated as non-callable objects (`str` in this case).

Any hacker thoughts?

**UPD:**

- The decorated function can be called by anyone.
- The arguments to the decorated function can be anything.
- The `*keys` argument can be filled in only by code author.

It's intended use is for example:

```
@ratelimit('some_custom_id_func(["by-username", username])').at('5/15s')
def login(username, password):
    ...
```

**UPD[2]:**

What if:

```
# get dict of arguments passed to the function
func_args = getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
# THE CHANGE IS HERE!
for func_arg_key in func_args.keys():
    func_args[func_arg_key] = str(func_args[func_arg_key]) 
# NOW INPUT IS SANITIZED (KINDA)?
# now these are made locally visible as normal variables inside the eval function
_keys = []
for key in keys:
    _key = eval(key, globals(), func_args)
    _keys.append(_key)
print(_keys)
```

Input sanitized?

**UPD[3]**

Imagine, we got rid of the `eval()`. Does this make it safer? If so, then why?

```
def ratelimit(*keys):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # get dict of arguments passed to the function
            func_args = getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
            for key in keys:
                print(key(func_args))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@ratelimit(lambda d: d['you'] + " and " + d['me'], lambda d: d['me'] + " or " + d['you'])
def you_and_me(you, me):
    print("you and me")


you_and_me("1", "2")
```

Comment: Before we can answer "is it safe", who has access to what?  Who is going to be able to write code using @safeornot?  Who is going to be able to call code that is decorated with @safeornot?  Who is creating the arguments to the calls to these methods?

Comment: Do you actually need to pass in `globals()`? One thing to make `eval` safer is to not provide any globals: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

Comment: @FrankYellin added a use-case for the function. I meant, that this function is actually going to be available as an http endpoint in some cases, so the arguments are anything.

Comment: @Lagerbaer https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html here it says that `globals()` can be accessed even with empty dict passed in. Didn't try, but no reason to not believe. I did make it optional, though, and by default it will pass in an empty dict.

Comment: Use `eval` when you want to execute arbitrary code, not when you want a *specific* feature that `eval` would happen to cover.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi cause I don't `eval` the variables themselves, only use them in the context. OK, gonna change something in the code, UPD.

Comment: I would try to somehow replace `eval` usage with `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @winwin If the arguments can be literally ***anything***, they might be objects with reimplemented `__radd__`, `__iadd__`, `__str__`, etc which call arbitrary code.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok, but would it be different, if a dictionary with arguments would be passed to a lambda function?

Comment: @VPfB I didn't find a way to pass in local variables to the `ast.literal_eval`. Is there a way?

Comment: @ekhumoro I updated the post, it seems to not make things any different.

Comment: @winwin I've lost sight now of what it is you're trying to control.

Comment: @winwin There is no direct way to pass values. You need to build a string to be evaluated with the current variable values in it. That's why I wrote "somehow". Maybe using `str.format()` or `string.Template.substitute`

Comment: @VPfB yeah, that would require to write a parser for global variables, which is not really something I'm keen on doing. I'll go with the `eval`, for as long as you know what you're doing and you sanitize your input, you must be good. I hope so, haha :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer I can give you is "I don't know".  I can't think of anything, but there are lots of people out there a lot smarter than me at breaking things.  I hate `eval`, and think every occurrence of eval is a security hole waiting to happen. You should avoid it at all costs.

If this were me, I'd write:

```
def login_logger(x, y):
   Do whatever you want here safely

@ratelimit(login_logger)
def login(x, y): ...
```

Have your `@ratelimit` call a logging function that takes the exact same arguments as the function it is wrapping.

Comment: The snatch here is that you're gonna have to write this kind of function for each function you want to put a decorator over. This is gonna look really-really ugly in the code and, what's more, you're gonna have to always explicitly write the arguments yourself. It really messes up the point of the decorator itself, since it becomes a pain to compose it in the first place, instead of "just add some water". You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah.  I agree.  But `eval` really terrifies me.  Even if this guy writes something that's 100% safe, the next programmer's going to come along, see this "pretty" tool, and write something that isn't safe.  I used to work in code security, and I've seen too many bugs caused by just this sort of thing.

Comment: I got rid of the `eval` function, please see the UPD. But I just don't see it really being any more safe. Still, if input is anything, and `eval` is used just to pass in variables, the same as dictionary here, what's the difference? How is `eval` more dangerous?

Comment: Google "Why is eval dangerous?"  If you have complete control over **everything** that is being passed to the `eval`, then maybe it's okay.  But you've already said that there is user input involved.  https://xkcd.com/327/. This is a SQL example rather than Python, but the same principle applies.